# Angularjs routing redirect me to default page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a navbar on my app:

```
<a ng-href="#!/organizations">Organizations</a>
<a ng-href="#!/organizations/users">Users</a>
```

When I click on `Organizations` I move to organizations' page but when I click to `Users` an application redicet me to default `Login` page. My folder structure:

```
├── organizations
│   ├── organization
│   │   ├── organization.html
│   │   └── organization.js
│   ├── organizations.html
│   ├── organizations.js
│   └── users
│       ├── users.html
│       └── users.js
```

A config from `users.js`:

```
.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('users', {
                parent: 'fd',
                url: 'organizations/users',
                views: {
                    '': {
                        templateUrl: 'components/organizations/users/users.html',
                        controller: 'UsersController as ctrl'
                    }
                }
            });
    }])
```

Can't find where I made a mistake.

Comment: try change to `url: '/organizations/users',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
 .state('users', {
            parent: 'fd',
            url: '/organizations/users',
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'components/organizations/users/users.html',
                    controller: 'UsersController as ctrl'
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the route correctly.
instead of `url: 'organizations/users'`

You need to specify like this
`url: '/organizations/users'`